# Iteratively printing every integer in a List

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Say I have a List of integers `l = [1,2]`

Which I want to print to `stdout`.

Doing `print l` produces `[1,2]`

Say I want to print the list without the braces

`map print l` produces

```
No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of `print'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (IO ()))
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

`:t print

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

So while I thought this would work I went ahead and tried:

```
map putStr $ map show l
```

Since I suspected a type mismatch from Integer to String was to blame. This produced the same error message as above.

I realize that I could do something like concatenating the list into a string, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

What's going on? How can I do this without constructing a string from the elements of the List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you're given a list `xs :: [a]` and function `f :: Monad m => a -> m b`. You want to apply the function `f` to each element of `xs`, yielding a list of actions, then sequence these actions. Here is how I would go about constructing a function, call it `mapM`, that does this. In the base case, `xs = []` is the empty list, and we simply return `[]`. In the recursive case, `xs` has the form `x : xs`. First, we want to apply `f` to `x`, giving the action `f x :: m b`. Next, we want recursively call `mapM` on `xs`. The result of performing the first step is a value, say `y`; the result of performing the second step is a list of values, say `ys`. So we collect `y` and `ys` into a list, then return them in the monad:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM f []       = return []
mapM f (x : xs) = f x >>= \y -> mapM f ys >>= \ys -> return (y : ys)
```

Now we can map a function like `print`, which returns an action in the `IO` monad, over a list of values to print: `mapM print [1..10]` does precisely this for the list of integers from one through ten. There is a problem, however: we aren't particularly concerned about collecting the results of printing operations; we're primarily concerned about their side effects. Instead of returning `y : ys`, we simply return `()`.

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) ->[a] -> m ()
mapM_ f []       = return ()
mapM_ f (x : xs) = f x >> mapM_ f xs
```

Note that `mapM` and `mapM_` can be defined without explicit recursion using the `sequence` and `sequence_` functions from the standard library, which do precisely what their names imply. If you look at the source code for `mapM` and `mapM_` in `Control.Monad`, you will see them implemented that way.

Comment: this answer has taught me more about Haskell then all the fiddling I've done previously. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So we end up with `[IO ()]`. This is a pure value, a list of `IO` actions. It won't actually print anything. Instead we want

```
mapM_ :: (a -> IO ()) -> [a] -> IO ()
```

The naming convention `*M` means that it operates over monads and `*_` means we throw away the value. This is like map except it sequences each action with `>>` to return an `IO` action.

As an example `mapM_ print [1..10]` will print each element on a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Haskell is very strongly typed, including code to perform IO!

When you write `print [1, 2]`, this is just a convenience wrapper for `putStrLn (show [1, 2])`, where show is a function that turns a (Show'able) object into a string.  `print` itself doesn't *do* anything (in the side effect sense of *do*), but it outputs an `IO()` action, which is sort of like a mini unrun "program" (if you excuse the sloppy language), which isn't "run" at its creation time, but which can be passed around for later execution.  You can verify the type in ghci

```
> :t print [1, 2] 
print [1, 2]::IO()
```

This is just an object of type `IO ()`....  You could throw this away right now and nothing would ever happen.  More likely, if you use this object in `main`, the IO code *will* run, side effects and all.

When you map multiple `putStrLn` (or `print`) functions onto a list, you still get an object whose type you can view in ghci

```
> :t map print [1, 2]
map print [1, 2]::[IO()]
```

Like before, this is just an object that you can pass around, and by itself it will not do anything.  But unlike before, the type is incorrect for usage in main, which expects an IO() object.  In order to use it, you need to convert it to this type.

There are many ways to do this conversion....  One way that I like is the `sequence` function.

```
sequence $ map print [1, 2]
```

which takes a list of IO actions (ie- mini "programs" with side effects, if you will forgive the sloppy language), and sequences them together as on IO action.  This code alone will now do what you want.

---

As jozefg pointed out, although `sequence` works, `sequence_` is a better choice here....
Sequence not only concatinates the stuff in the IO action, but also puts the return values in a list....  Since print's return value is IO(), the new return value becomes a useless list of ()'s (in IO).  :)

Comment: That's not correct.. I think you meant `sequence $ map print` but why not `mapM` in this case

Comment: The missing `map` was just a retype error, I've fixed it.  Other than that, I don't know why I get the downvote though, I use both `mapM` and `sequence` in my code, and I think `sequence` is both a useful and pedagogical alternative.  It helps to think of each IO() action as a separate piece of code, which can be sequenced together.  Although useful, I think of mapM as more of a clever way to make functional code look like imperative code.  Don't get me wrong, I don't hate it, I just think it is less confusing to understand sequence first.

Comment: I -1'd because typo and because both `mapM` and `sequence` generate useless lists of `[()]`. I'd say that `mapM_` is actually the correct thing here.

Comment: I could also use `sequence_` instead of `sequence`....  I will add it in as a note at the end to avoid confusion to the main point though.

Comment: Note that the more idiomatic `mapM_ f xs` is in fact defined as `sequence_ (map f xs)` (see, e.g., [the library source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#mapM_)). There's also `forM_ xs f = mapM xs f`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library:

```
[1,2,3] ^! each . act print
```

Answer (score 0):

You might write your own function, too:

```
Prelude> let l = [1,2]

Prelude> let f [] = return (); f (x:xs) = do print x; f xs

Prelude> f l 
1
2
```