# List of IO Strings

Tags: haskell, io

I'm new to Haskell and FP so this question may seem silly.

I have a line of code in my main function

```
let y = map readFile directoryContents
```

where directoryContents is of type `[FilePath]`. This in turn (I think) makes y type `[IO String]` , so a list of strings - each string containing the contents of each file in `directoryContents`.

I have a functions written in another module that work on `[String]` and `String` but I'm unclear as how to call/use them now because y is of type `[IO String]`. Any pointers?

---

**EDIT:**

It was suggested to me that I want to use `mapM` instead of `map`, so:

`let y = mapM readFile directoryContents` , and `y` is now type `IO [String]`, what do I do from here?

Comment: FYI- this is basically the "input" version of a similar question earlier today- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203811/iteratively-printing-every-integer-in-a-list.  You might find the answers to that question interesting also.

Answer (score 34):

You're correct, the type is `y :: [IO String]`.

Well, there are essentially main two parts here:

### How to turn [IO String] into IO [String]

`[IO String]` is a list of of `IO` actions and what we need is an IO action that carries a list of strings (that is, `IO [String]`). Luckily, the function sequence provides exactly what we need:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
y' = sequence y :: IO [String]
```

Now the `mapM` function can simplify this, and we can rewrite `y'` as:

```
y' = mapM readFile directoryContents
```

`mapM` does the sequence for us.

### How to get at the [String]

Our type is now `IO [String]`, so the question is now "How do we get the [String] out of the IO?" This is what the function `>>=` (bind) does:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  -- Specialized to IO, that type is:
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

We also have a function `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` which can put a value "into" `IO`.

So with these two functions, if we have some function `f :: [String] -> SomeType`, we can write:

```
ourResult = y' >>= (\theStringList -> return (f theStringList))  :: IO SomeType
```

Functions can be "chained" together with the `>>=` function. This can be a bit unreadable at times, so Haskell provides `do` notation to make things visually simpler:

```
ourResult = do
  theStringList <- y'
  return $ f theStringList
```

The compiler internally turns this into `y' >>= (\theStringList -> f theStringList)`, which is the same as the `y' >>= f` that we had before.

### Putting it all together

We probably don't actually want `y'` floating around, so we can eliminate that and arrive at:

```
ourResult = do
  theStringList <- mapM readFile directoryContents
  return $ f theStringList
```

### Even more simplification

It turns out, this doesn't actually need the full power of `>>=`. In fact, all we need is `fmap`! This is because the function `f` only has one argument "inside" of `IO` and we aren't using any other previous `IO` result: we're making a result then immediately using it.

Using the law

```
fmap f xs  ==  xs >>= return . f
```

we can rewrite the `>>=` code to use fmap like this:

```
ourResult = fmap f (mapM readFile directoryContents)
```

If we want to be even more terse, there is an infix synonym for `fmap` called `<$>`:

```
ourResult = f <$> mapM readFile directoryContents
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation! just one last thing a little unrelated if you don't mind: directoryContents contains the files ".." and "." and I think I'm getting and openFile error when readFile tries to open ".." and ".". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You could use `drop 2`. `drop 2 [".", "..", "a", "b", "c"]  ==  ["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: A good and comprehensive explanation, but I'd changed `fmap` to `liftM` to not to confuse up things, because `fmap` is defined for functors, whereas `>>=` and `liftM` are for monads. Heck, we still don't have `Monad` as a subclass of `Functor` :(

Comment: @user3369427 I'd also propose to filter a list of `FilePath`s before reading with `filterM doesFileExist`, because if you have some subfolders in your directory, the current code will b0rk as well.