# extract value of a from IO (Maybe a)

Tags: haskell

I am making a game with gloss and got this:

```
pictureMapBasic :: [Picture] -> Picture -> [Picture] 
pictureMapBasic picL pic = picL ++ (loadJuicyPNG "lib\assets\back.png")
```

How do I take this IO (Maybe Picture) (from loadJuicyPNG) and turn it into a Picture and add it to the list?

Comment: To start with, your return type will have to be `IO [Picture]`...

Comment: [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://sigfpe.blogspot.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html)

Comment: Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213692/list-of-io-strings/22213844#22213844) could help?